# Showing thumbnails for docx pdf for uploaded files using JQuery and Django

Tags: django, pdf, documentation, thumbnails, jquery-file-upload

I am using dropzone.js to upload files to Django backend and it displays the default thumbnail for files except images. How can I add a snapshot of a file, doc/pdf/ppt/excel types? Is there any package out there? Googled it but not showing that much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use preview-generator? https://pypi.org/project/preview-generator/

Comment: It seems it doesn't support .doc..